# Tool for human interpretation of XTerm escape sequences?

Tags: terminal, console, xterm, ncurses

Basically, I want a tool to interpret the raw output of commands that output ANSI color codes, terminal reset codes, etc. in the Linux/Unix/macOS terminal. Something based on https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html would be ideal. Does something like this already exist? If not, it wouldn't be too hard to write a tool to read codes from standard input and translate it using this page.

Comment: This seems to be an XY problem. What would you use this for?

Comment: There's nothing particularly stopping you writing a _terminfo_ definition that outputs readable text instead of colour codes and other attributes